# How to save a Date in Firebase using Kotlin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, datepicker

I am trying to save the date in Firebase and my app is crashing. Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my model

```
class Date (val id: String, val mDate: String)
```

Here is my MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    internal lateinit var dpDate: DatePicker

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dpDate = findViewById(R.id.dpDate) as DatePicker
    }

    private fun saveDate(v: View) {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        builder.append("Current Date: ")
        builder.append((dpDate.month + 1).toString() + "/")//month is 0 based
        builder.append(dpDate.dayOfMonth.toString() + "/")
        builder.append(dpDate.year)

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dates")
        val dateID = ref.push().key
        val mDate = builder.toString()
        val date = Date(dateID!!, mDate)
        ref.child(dateID).setValue(date).addOnCompleteListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dpDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
    />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:onClick="saveDate"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what the error is in the logcat:

> Process: com.simona.kotlin.datepicker, PID: 23537
>      java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Could not find method saveDate(View) in a parent or ancestor Context** for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnGet'
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am learning how to pick a date and then save it into firebase using the code above. The picker works well, when I click save the app crashes. I tried using the debugger but the error I'm seeing I haven't seen before, so therefore is useless to me. I hope it make more sense to you. Here is the message I get in the Logcat. I've updated the request. Thanks again.

Comment: Make `saveDate()` public

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :)